# bash vi mode: what is (arg: N)?

Tags: bash, vi

I am using vi mode in a bash shell.

If I enter <strike>insert</strike> command mode and type a number from 1-9 (eg: 5, in the example below), I get the following prompt:

```
(arg: 5) <cursor>
```

What does this mean?
I can't seem to do anything useful with this prompt, and I don't know what its purpose is.

I even poked into the bash sources, which in turn gets into the GNU Readline sources.

The function that ends up being called is `rl_vi_arg_digit`, which then calls `rl_digit_argument`, which displays the `(arg: N)` prompt. But I can't see from comments or related code what it's actually *used for*.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually *exited* insert mode and are in command mode.  The number is an argument that can be used with motion keys, just as in `vi`:  e.g. `5h` moves left 5 characters.   Likewise you can say `5s` to delete the next 5 characters and go into insert mode (`s`ubstitute for 5 characters).

Comment: whoops, you're right about command mode - i'll fix the question